# c:forEach not binding the values of the components inside it

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl, jsf-2.2

I am migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2. The below simple c:forEach with a text box is not binding the value with backing bean property.

```
<c:forEach 
    items="#{handlerBean.activeList}" 
    var="row" 
    varStatus="status"
>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{row.firstName}" />   
                #{row.firstName}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</c:forEach>
```

Is there something I am missing with JSF 2.2 JSTL tags?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem is not visible in information provided so far. It works just fine for me and anyone else when copypasted into a `<h:form>` of a further empty templateless page in a blank project with most minimal configuration and most recent versions and a standard backing bean. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).